# How to avoid vertical scroll in a css grid

Tags: flexbox, css-grid

Trying to avoid vertical scroll in my grid inside a flexbox [codepen](https://codepen.io/killjoy2013/pen/ZExXXVw)

tried to use justify-content & justify-items as flex-start in home_main class. But that did not avoid vertical scroll.

what would you suggest?

```
.home_main { 
  padding: 4rem 0;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-items: flex-start;
  align-items: center;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

comment

```
width: 100%;
```

in your ".navbar" class

Comment: it's already there.

Comment: I said comment it

Comment: nothing changed :(